# What is the difference between the adjectives/adverbs "broad" and "wide"? the nouns "breadth" and "width"?

Tags: word-choice, adjectives, adverbs, collocation

*Broad* and *wide* are near synonyms but only *near*, since "*a broad smile*" is a more common collocation than "*a wide smile*", and you can say "*eyes wide open*" but not "*eyes broad open*".

*Breadth* and *width* seem to be closer synonyms since both are defined in Collins Dictionary Online as:

> the linear extent or measurement of something from side to side

Why are the adjectives/adverbs *broad* and *wide* not as interchangeable as the nouns *breadth* and *width* seem to be?

Comment: I would have to disagree with the statement that a smile can't be wide--and so would the Telegraph: http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/newsvideo/10134201/Queen-beams-a-wide-smile-as-her-horse-Estimate-wins-Gold-Cup.html

Comment: Interestingly both words are of Germanic origin, and come to us from Old English. Usually when there are two words that mean almost exactly the same thing, one will be of Saxon the other of Norman origin. But that is not so in this case, it seems.

Comment: @Louel: I can only bow…

Answer (score 3):

To quote from the late Charles Fillmore's Deixis [Lecture on "Space"](http://www.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/2-Space.pdf) (p.24) on *wide*:

> In expressing measurement of objects that are viewed as having a spatial orientation, the adjectives that accompany these measurement indications are selected according to a number of assumptions we make about the salient dimensions and the specific spatial orientation of the objects in question.
>
> Consider first the way in which the word *wide* is used in measurement expressions for roughly oblong objects. Suppose there is a plot of land 75 feet by 200 feet in dimension out in the middle of nowhere, and you ask somebody to go out and measure it and to report to you the results of his measurements. He will probably come back and tell you that the lot is *75 feet **wide*** and *200 feet **long***.
>
> Now build a road along the 200 foot length of this lot in a way to suggest that this is a lot that has one of its borders along a road in some future housing development, and ask somebody to go out and measure the lot. This time you will be told that the lot is *200 feet **wide*** and *75 feet **deep***.
>
> Putting the road alongside of the lot will have served to designate one border of that lot as its **front**, and when an object to be measured has a front/back orientation in space, the word *wide* is used in measuring the left-to-right extent along its front, and the word used for indicating the measurement of its front-to-back distance is the word *deep*.

*Broad* does not have this particular detail; it seems to be usable for the smaller dimension of any oriented oblong, and also to indicate the side-to-side dimension of any oriented path (a broad trail), which is a special case.

Comment: I'm not sure this captures the assumptions that go into describing a smile or shoulders as _broad._ That is, I think there are still assumptions, just different ones. Perhaps in contrast to height rather than length.

Comment: @John Lawler: I like your answer since it goes to show that a choice of words is never random; there are always good reasons – reasons you can explain to someone – for choosing a word rather than another one.

Comment: It's always the speaker's decision what to say and how to say it. Why they may choose one way over another involves a **lot** of choices, mostly unconscious. You might as well ask about how one goes about choosing chocolate cake for dessert instead of peach cobbler. People vary in just about every way.

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion, initially at least,

- *wide* had to do with the space between two objects, how wide apart they are, whereas
- *broad* had to do with the space taken up by an object, from side to side.

When you say "eyes wide open", you mean there is a great space between the upper and lower eyelids, not that the eyes themselves are particularly large or protruding.

When you say "a broad smile", you do not mean there is a great space between the upper and lower lips, but that the corners of the mouth stretch so far out that the smile takes up quite some space on the face, extends from one side of it to the other.

This distinction seems lost in *breadth* and *width*, although I am under the impression that you use *breadth* when the object has one main, obvious dimension, e.g. "broad shoulders", and *width* when the object — a table or a board, for instance — obviously has different dimensions: length, width, height, thickness, etc.

Comment: The *river is wide* and so are the *wide open spaces*. You also *cast a wide net*. I don't think *wide* only deals with edges.

Comment: Absolutely, the space between the banks of the river, the space encompassed in the horizon, wherever you turn, same thing for netting or mesh. Space encompassed in limits, boundaries, and not space taken up by an object (broad, breadth)…

Comment: A 6" inch wide board? A wide noodle (as well as a broad noodle)?

Comment: Broadway or Wideway?

Comment: @bib: the width of a board… see my edited answer

Comment: While I think you have a point about eyes (or doors) being open wide, I agree with bib that wide doesn't strictly mean a gap. It's just that we use _wide_ more than _broad_ to describe gaps. And note that rivers can be either _wide_ or _broad._

Comment: Although interestingly, Etymology Online notes that _wide_ is: perhaps from PIE *wi-ito-, from root *wi- "apart, away."